How to identify and catch Delphi EAccessViolation that happens TDataModule Destroy?
I have transformed Delphi 2009 desktop app into console app (added {$APPTYPE CONSOLE} and avoided creation of the MainForm, instead I am creating TDataModule descendants and doing work with them) and now I am receiving MadExcept call stack:
exception class    : EAccessViolation
exception message  : Access violation at address 0085840B in module 'HRSuite.exe'. Read of address 0C0B7260.

main thread ($4cc0):
0085840b +03f HRSuite.exe  DBClient            1212  +3 TCustomClientDataSet.CloseCursor
00567fef +0a7 HRSuite.exe  DB                 10601 +21 TDataSet.SetActive
00567df0 +004 HRSuite.exe  DB                 10553  +0 TDataSet.Close
00559c2e +012 HRSuite.exe  DB                  4066  +3 TField.Destroy
0049ed23 +047 HRSuite.exe  Classes            11584  +9 TComponent.DestroyComponents
0049eb17 +04f HRSuite.exe  Classes            11486  +8 TComponent.Destroy
0049fd42 +066 HRSuite.exe  Classes            12519  +6 TDataModule.Destroy
005c9384 +0b8 HRSuite.exe  HRBaseDMU            349 +22 THRBaseDM.Destroy
0049ed23 +047 HRSuite.exe  Classes            11584  +9 TComponent.DestroyComponents
005353e9 +035 HRSuite.exe  Forms               1755  +9 DoneApplication
0054325a +022 HRSuite.exe  Forms              11116  +1 Finalization
00405ac9 +039 HRSuite.exe  System             12865 +20 FinalizeUnits
00468428 +054 HRSuite.exe  madExcept                    InterceptFinalizeUnits
00468430 +000 HRSuite.exe  madExcept                    InterceptHalt0FinalizeUnits
00405ec5 +09d HRSuite.exe  System             13632 +61 @Halt0
010cabb9 +151 HRSuite.exe  HRSuite              545 +37 initialization
75a0fcc7 +017 KERNEL32.DLL                              BaseThreadInitThunk

From what I see, I tried to at least identify which DataModule has exceptions in Destroy:
procedure THRBaseDM.DataModuleDestroy(Sender: TObject);
var tmp: Integer;
begin
  Writeln(Self.Name);
  Writeln('BASE before destroy: '+Self.Name);
  inherited;
  Writeln('BASE after destroy: '+Self.Name);
end;

But the final output lines are:
FreeDaysDM
BASE before destroy: FreeDaysDM
BASE after destroy: FreeDaysDM
An error occurred in the application.

I expected that there would be 'BASE before destroy:...' without closing notification and that could be the way to identify the offending DataModule, but there is no opening notification without closing notification, so - I should try to get information about offending DataModule in some different way. But how?

OnDestroy is not the place to catch an exception, instead, one has to override destructor itself in the data module:
public
    destructor Destroy; override;

and then
destructor THRBaseDM.Destroy;
var i: Integer;
begin
  Writeln('REAL BASE before destroy: '+Self.Name);
  try
    //... some large business or technical code
    inherited;
  except
    on E: Exception do begin
      Writeln('REAL '+Self.name);
      Writeln('REAL '+E.Message);
    end;
  end;
  Writeln('REAL BASE after destroy: '+Self.Name);
end;

And such overwrite brings us expected error reports.
